# Union data structure alignment

Tags: c, struct, standards, unions

I was working with some (of what I thought was) bad code that had a union like:

```
union my_msg_union
{
  struct message5;
  char buffer[256]
} message;
```

The buffer was filled with 256 bytes from comms. The struct is something like:

```
struct message5 {
 uint8 id;
 uint16 size;
 uint32 data;
 uint8 num_ids;
 uint16 ids[4];
} message5d
```

The same code was being compiled on heaps of architectures (8bit AVR, 16bit phillips, 32bit arm, 32bit x86 and amd64).

The problem I thought was the use of the union: The code just a blob of serial recieved bytes into the buffer, then reads the values out through the struct, without considering alignment/padding of the struct.

Sure enough, a quick look at sizeof(message5d) on different systems gave different results.

What surprised me however is that whenever the union with the char [] existed, all instances of all structs of that type, on all systems, dropped their padding/alignment, and made sure to be sequential bytes.

Is this a C standard or just something that compiler authors have put in to 'help'?

Comment: Not only is it not a C standard, it's not allowed ... the size of every instance of struct message5 must be the same.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that with a short program that outputs inconsistent sizes?

Comment: There is no inconsistent sizes. I meant that when I compiled without the union, the size is different to when I compile with the union.

Comment: @Staven You are confused. My statement is correct ... the compiler cannot change the size of struct message5 based on whether it is shared in some union with some other object. This applies to his statement "all instances of all structs of that type, on all systems, dropped their padding/alignment" -- an implementation is not allowed to do that.

Comment: @Staven I didn't say anything about them not being implementation dependent; I said something quite different. However the implementation pads and aligns the struct, it must do so consistently, else different instances of the same struct in the same program can be different, which is not allowed. The sizeof a struct is established and fixed when it is defined; it cannot change just because it's in a union with a char[256].

Comment: @Staven "Do you mean that sizeof(my_msg_union) is always the same?" -- No he doesn't mean that; he wrote about sizeof(struct message5).

Comment: @Staven I didn't say anything about assigning to unions; you keep reading words that aren't there and ignoring the words that are. Yes, the size changed when he recompiles with/without the union defined -- **which is not allowed**. Consider two source files, both including a header defining struct message5, one of which is compiled with the union and one without -- sizeof(struct message5) must be the same in both instances (and all the padding must be the same too, else offsetof will give different values). Get it?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your use of "instance", hence the mystery. Welp, that's 30 minutes wasted. :V

Comment: @JimBalter: I don't see why it isn't allowed. The struct padding only needs to be consistent in a single compilation. What is not allowed is two instances of the same struct having inconsistent alignment - this is not what is being observed. When compiled with a union, ALL instances of the struct will have one form of alignment (apparently without padding) regardless of weather they're in the union or not. When compiled without union ALL instances of the struct will have another form of alignment (maybe with padding). They're consistent in a single program image.

Comment: So show *two* programs that output inconsistent sizes.

Comment: @slebetman That would be reasonable if the compiler could see the entire program at once. This is not the case with most modern compilers. Source files can be compiled separately and linked into a program later. The compiler must ensure consistent struct size and alignment for all source files, including those it has not seen yet.

Comment: @slebetman: whatever layout the compiler adopts for `struct message5` must be consistent at all points in the program. The compiler is not allowed to change the layout of the structure depending on whether the structure appears in a `union` (or inside another `struct`) or whether it is free-standing; in all circumstances, the layout of the structure must be the same. That's what Jim is saying.  (And if separate modules — object files — are created with different compiler options that give different layouts, then linking those modules together yields undefined behaviour!)

Comment: Yes, as I said, they're consistent at all points in the program when compiled if a union is used. They're also consistent at all points in the program when a union is not used. But two different programs - one which uses unions and one which doesn't - don't need to have the same alignment. THIS IS WHAT IS OBSERVED - when a program is compiled with unions it has a different layout compared to when it is recompiled with the union removed from source code.

Comment: @slebetman Can you show a pair of programs which exhibit such behaviour in practice, on any platform, with any compiler?

Comment: @slebetman The fact that this *particular* program doesn't have two different object files, one of which uses a union and the other doesn't, is irrelevant. If the compiler does what is being discussed, then one can trivially create such a program, which would be standards-conforming but which would not run correctly. Therefore, once again, the compiler cannot do that. The only way for it to be able to do that is remember whether it had ever, in the history of the implementation, created a .o with the other layout. Extant compilers aren't magical.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "created with different compiler options" -- yes, this is important. A compiler invoked with two different sets of options is two different implementations in the sense of "implementation" of the standard.

Comment: @slebetman "Yes, as I said, ... two different programs" -- did you see n.m.'s comment above yours? You appear to have completely ignored it, but it is essential; the issue is two different *object modules*. Those are the units of compilation, not programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code demonstrates the opposite behaviour from the one you describe:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct message5
{
    uint8_t id;
    uint16_t size;
    uint32_t data;
    uint8_t num_ids;
    uint16_t ids[4];
};

#if !defined(NO_UNION)
union my_msg_union
{
    struct message5 msg;
    char buffer[256];
};
#endif /* NO_UNION */

struct data
{
    char const *name;
    size_t offset;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct data offsets[] =
    {
        { "message5.id", offsetof(struct message5, id) },
        { "message5.size", offsetof(struct message5, size) },
        { "message5.data", offsetof(struct message5, data) },
        { "message5.num_ids", offsetof(struct message5, num_ids) },
        { "message5.ids", offsetof(struct message5, ids) },
#if !defined(NO_UNION)
        { "my_msg_union.msg.id", offsetof(union my_msg_union, msg.id) },
        { "my_msg_union.msg.size", offsetof(union my_msg_union, msg.size) },
        { "my_msg_union.msg.data", offsetof(union my_msg_union, msg.data) },
        { "my_msg_union.msg.num_ids", offsetof(union my_msg_union, msg.num_ids) },
        { "my_msg_union.msg.ids", offsetof(union my_msg_union, msg.ids) },
#endif /* NO_UNION */
    };
    enum { NUM_OFFSETS = sizeof(offsets) / sizeof(offsets[0]) };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_OFFSETS; i++)
        printf("%-25s  %3zu\n", offsets[i].name, offsets[i].offset);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks, 64-bit compilation):

```
message5.id                  0
message5.size                2
message5.data                4
message5.num_ids             8
message5.ids                10
my_msg_union.msg.id          0
my_msg_union.msg.size        2
my_msg_union.msg.data        4
my_msg_union.msg.num_ids     8
my_msg_union.msg.ids        10
```

The offsets within the union are the same as the offsets within the structure, as the C standard requires.

You would have to give a complete compiling counter-example based on the code above, and specify which compiler and platform you are compiling on to get your deviant answer — if indeed you can reproduce the deviant answer.

I note that I had to change `uint8` etc to `uint8_t`, but I don't think that makes any difference.  If it does, you need to specify which header you get the names like `uint8` from.

---

Code updated to be compilable with or without `union`.  Output when compiled with `-DNO_UNION`:

```
message5.id                  0
message5.size                2
message5.data                4
message5.num_ids             8
message5.ids                10
```

Comment: You need two sources - one with union and one without - to demonstrate what is observed (or not). Of course in a single program all instances of the struct will have the same layout. But what is observed is if you then removed the union from source that layout may (or may not, depends on the compiler) be different.

Comment: @slebetman: I don't think I agree, but it is trivial to arrange for the code to be compiled without the union, and the output for the structure is the same as it was with the union — of course.

Comment: @slebetman When the compiler compiles a source with/without the union, it cannot know whether it will be later given another source without/with the union, with the two object files linked into the same programs -- but it would have to know that to be able to compile the struct differently and be conforming. It's not logically impossible, but it is absurd, and nomologically impossible. So the fact stands, as I said, that a compiler can't do that.

Comment: @slebetman "You need two sources ... Of course in a single program ..." -- Do you understand that there is not a 1-1 correspondence between sources and programs, that programs are linked from multiple sources? Everything you have written here is as if you do not understand this ... what you have written depends on the absence of separate compilation ... but C is not Pascal.